# Программа, которая выводит все простые числа в диапазоне от M до N

Tags: c++, visual-c++, простые-числа

Хотел написать программу, которая выводила бы все простые числа в диапазоне от M до N. При попытке компиляции возникла куча ошибок. Посмотрите пожалуйста, скажите где недочёты?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int m;
    int n;
    int a;

    cin >> "Input M" >> m >> "\n";
    cin >> "Input N" >> n >> "\n";

    metka:
    for (; m <= n; m++ ) {
        for (a = 2; a <= m; a++) {
            if (m % a == 0) goto metka;
            else continue;
        }
        cout << m << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам только почему не компилируется, или и почему никуда не годится - тоже?

Не компилируется, потому что `cin` предназначен для **чтения**, а не вывода на экран. Надо так:

```
cout << "Input M: ";
cin >> m;
cout << "Input N: ";
cin  >> n;
```

И еще -

```
(m % a = 0)
```

Тут вы пытаетесь присвоить числу число, а не сравниваете. Надо

```
(m % a == 0)
```

После этого она скомпилируется, и тут время вспомнить о моем вопросе - "*Вам только почему не компилируется, или и почему никуда не годится - тоже?*"

**Update**

Начнем пояснять, почему не годится. Итак, для ЛЮБОГО числа `m`, когда мы крутанем внутренний цикл, для как минимум `a==m` получится `m%a == 0`, и переход на "наша песня хороша, начинай сначала". Т.е. с теми же `m` и `n` начинаем те же действия. Вечный цикл...

Да и проверять на делимость, последовательно ДЕЛЯ НА ВСЕ подряд числа до самого этого числа - неверно. Как минимум, неэффективно. Зачем проверять, делится ли, скажем, 100 на 30? Если бы делилось, то понятно, что делилось бы и на число порядка 100/30 :) - т.е. проверять достаточно до корня квадратного из проверяемого числа.

Т.е. цикл вывода должен иметь вид примерно

```
for(int i = m; i <= n; ++i)
{
    if (isPrime(i))
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

где `isPrime(i)` - проверка на простоту.

Вариант ваш (вернее, что вы хотели написать):

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Как минимум, можно проверять только до корня, т.е.

```
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
        if (n%i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Можно сразу уполовинить цикл, проверяя делимость на 2 отдельно, а в цикле - только на нечетные значения, но это уж вы самостоятельно :)

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснили. И да, хотелось бы узнать почему программа никуда не годится...

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Если уж оптимизировать, то и `i * i` в цикле надо бы заменить на `i <= sqrtn` и вычислять `sqrtn` один раз

Comment: @avp Куда больше толку - проверка по заготовленной таблице простых чисел :) Кстати, реально у меня цикл, как в оригинале, на очень чуть-чуть, но быстрее цикла `for(int i = 3, sq = sqrt(n)+0.5; i <= sq; i += 2)` - считал диапазон от 2 до 10000000.

Comment: @Harry, странно. Надо бы глянуть, во что они компилируются

Comment: Покрутил немного (несколько десятков  раз с -O3 и -Os и разным количеством). У меня `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz  Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-130-generic #156-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 08:53:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609`.  С предвычислением sqrt в большинстве случаев немного быстрее. На малых N (100000) разброс очень большой (от 10000 до 32000 clocks, в большинстве запусков вокруг 12000). Если брать минимумы, то с sqrt быстрее. Ладно, предоставим все остальные игры автору вопроса.